# Why people uses @Autowired for constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have seen many people using `@Autowired` annotation in constructor to inject dependencies like as shown below

```
@Service
public class Employee {

 private EmployeeService employeeService;
 
 @Autowired
 public Employee(EmployeeService employeeService) {
   this.employeeService = employeeService;
 }
 :
 :
}
```

as per my knowledge nowadays Spring is so advanced and the Spring constructor/setter DI works even without `@Autowired` like as shown below

```
@Service
public class Employee {

 private EmployeeService employeeService;

 public Employee(EmployeeService employeeService) {
   this.employeeService = employeeService;
 }
 :
 :
}
```

Like to know is there any reason why people annotate constructor with `@Autowired` annotation to inject dependencies.

Can someone please help me on this

Comment: You can have more than one constructor and Spring will not know which one to use without `@Autowired`

Comment: because of copy/paste mentality of 8 out of 10 devs. I have around 20 developers at my work, and around 16 of them, have an extremely poor understanding of how spring works, internally.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev so if we have multiple constructor we should choose the most useful one and annotate with `@Autowired` for getting injected via DI in another places right? Also do we really need to have multiple constructors in spring context nowadays

Comment: Do note that having multiple constructors is [not a good practice](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no technical reason to do this (except if you have multiple constructors etc.). The most likely reason is, that people have learned to use it, when Spring didn't support the autodetection of the constructor and when it was still necessary, and as the saying goes, old habits die hard. Also, if you search for any examples, you still find a lot of tutorials, where the annotation is used, so that is another reason. It's the same as with the `@Repository` annotation on Spring Data interfaces. That annotation is just plain wrong there, but there are a lot of questions on this site, where people added this in their code.

Comment: 1+ for `@Repository` and interfaces! it's ridiculous how many times you can answer and explain to people the same thing and they still use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right - you don't need use annotation `@Autowired` constructor with DI.
I think is couple of reasons:

- developer doesn't known that is not necessairy
- developer use annotation to emphasize that it's DI
- the programmer doesn't trust Spring and wants to make sure DI works
- application was written in lower Spring and upgraded to newer - annotation is artifact of it

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use `@Autowired` annotation just to enhance code readability so that other developers can read and understand code more easily.